# Binding Grid Datacontext to Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Is it possible to bind model as property to grid datacontext?

Example

**Model**

```
public class Model
{
   field1....
   field2....
}
```

Then create item

```
   private Model _newModel;
   public Model NewModel
   {
        get { return _newModel; }
        set { _newModel = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
   }


NewModel = (new Model({
  field1 = "field1",
  field2 = "field2"
});
```

So is it possible to bind  NewModel  to grid datacontext

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding NewModel}" >
    <Label Content="{Binding NewModel.field1}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding NewModel.field2}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sure, the Bindings would be `{Binding field1}` then, and field1 must be a public property, not a field.

Comment: Is it a Grid that is on it's own somewhere? or is it in a listview or a listbox? And Model needs properties for Binding to work

Comment: NewModel is Propierty. Inside the model field1 and field2 also properties. I want to bind model to grid as itemtemplate bind model

Comment: Look into DataTemplates and we need to know more about your xaml and how you use it.

Comment: If you have a chunk of markup that logically should have a different datacontext then this is a potential candidate for refactoring into a usercontrol. If that piece of ui is switched out then datatemplate based viewmodel first is a good pattern to consider. I think this might be what @Xanimax is alluding to.

Comment: I forgot add OnPropertyChanges to properties in model. All works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding Path is relative to binding source, which is equal to DataContext by default.

Child elements (Labels here) *inherit* DataContext from parent (Grid). So Labels have `NewModel`  for DataContext.

So binding should look like:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding NewModel}" >
    <Label Content="{Binding field1}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding field2}" />
</Grid>
```

And in model properties must look like this

```
private string _prop;
public string Prop
{
    get { return _prop; }
    set { _prop = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```